# RegEx for matching a string after a string up to a comma

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

Here is a sample string.

`"BLAH, blah, going to the store &^5, light Version 12.7(2)L6, anyway
plus other stuff Version 3.3.4.6.  Then goes on an on for several lines..."`

I want to capture only the first version number without including the word version if possible but not include the periods and parenthesis. The result would stop when it encounters a comma. The result would be:
`"1272L6"`

I don't want it to include other instances of version in the text.  Can this be done?

I've tried `(?<=version)[^,]*`  I know it does not address removing the periods and parens and does not address the subsequent versions.

Comment: It can be done with two steps:1) extract that substring you need 2) remove non-aphanumeric chars from it. You can't match disjoint chars with one match operation and I doubt you may use a regex replace operation with capturing groups/backreferences unless the format of the match is always the same.

Comment: How strict is the format of version?  It's difficult to specify a solution without the exact grammar.  Could it also be  **12.7(23)L6** or **12(2.7)L62**, etc?

Answer (score 0):

[This exact RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/UY7HyR/2/), maybe not the best solution, but it might help you to get `1272L6`:

```
([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{1})\(([0-9]{1})\)([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})
```

It creates four groups (where `$1$2$3$4` is your target `1272L6`) and passes <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>)</kbd> and <kbd>(</kbd>.

You might change `{1}` to other numbers of repetitions, such as `{1,2}`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the version number is fixed on format but not on the specific digits or letters, you could do this.

```
  String s = "this is a test 12.7(2)L6, 13.7(2)L6, 14.7(2)L6";
  String reg = "(\\d\\d\\.\\d\\(\\d\\)[A-Z]\\d),";
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile(reg).matcher(s);
  if (m.find()) { // should only find first one
     System.out.println(m.group(1).replaceAll("[.()]", ""));
  }
```